# Handle Android Bluetooth LE Disconnect Notification

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth

I have finished developing an Android app that connects to a Bluetooth LE (Low Energy, 4.0) Pedometer. Everything works great except I am not handling disconnection scenarios at all and I want to make sure I am.

I want to make sure that if the user turns off the smartphone Bluetooth or powers off the Bluetooth Pedometer device that I can get notified immediately. I have figured out how to do this and the code is below. However, I am not sure how to talk to my Activity (any activity the user may be on) from my receiver class when I detect a Bluetooth disconnect. In this scenario, I envision a message appear in the current activity telling the user that they must turn on Bluetooth again to continue.

So, I guess my question is how do I notify any one of my activities (depending on which one the user is on) from a Receiver class?

Thanks!

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

 <receiver android:name="com.pedometerproject" android:exported="false">
 <intent-filter>
   <action android:name"android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

BluetoothTest.java

```
 public class BluetoothTest extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {

       if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(intent.getAction()))
       {
           if (intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,-1) == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF)
           {
             //WORKS TO HERE. HOW DO I TELL THE CURRENT ACTIVITY THE USER IS ON THAT BLUETOOTH HAS DISCONNECTED?
           }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have generally two ways... Simpliest way will be register receiver in all your activities.

You may add custom Application class (or just singletone object) which implements Observer pattern, and subscribe on it in every activity. (subscribe in OnResume, unsubscribe in onPause)

In my apps, I prefer first way, because it's simplier.But second way is faster, if that's critical for you.

Here is my code for default fragment wrapper:

```
public abstract class BleServiceFragment  extends Fragment{

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;
private BluetoothLeService mService=null;

protected abstract BroadcastReceiver getBleReceiver();
private IntentFilter filter =makeFilter();
boolean receiverRegistered=false;

protected IntentFilter makeFilter(){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Const.Intent.BLE_CARD_LIST);
    return filter;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
            (BluetoothManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

    // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getActivity().finish();
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
    {

            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

    }

    getActivity().registerReceiver(getBleReceiver(), filter);
    receiverRegistered=true;
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if(receiverRegistered)
    {
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(getBleReceiver());
        receiverRegistered=false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(receiverRegistered)
    {
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(getBleReceiver());
        receiverRegistered=false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // User chose not to enable Bluetooth.
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        getActivity().finish();
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I just inherit all my working fragments from it,implementing `getBleReceiver()` and overriding `makeFilter()` if needed.

Comment: Hey Raiv, thanks for the detailed response and code. I really appreciate it. Our current implementation is not using fragments and time is of essence. Can you provide an example of doing it the second way? Thanks!

Comment: you can use activity instead of fragment, code will be almost same. i post fragment just because i had sources for it)